# Whitespace between product image and gallery on initial load of lightbox product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, lightbox

I'm trying to understand why whitespace appears between the main product image and the product gallery on this page: http://etica.co.nz/product/mini-icosidodecahedron-ring-bearer-box/

Clicking on the middle image will remove the whitespace.

Why would it be doing this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so eventually managed to figure out that it was due to a couple of optimization plugins that were interfering with WooCommerce's image slider: JetPack's lazy loading and SG Optimizer.

Deactivated SG Optimizer and added the following to my child theme's functions.php:

```
function is_lazyload_activated()
{
    $condition = is_product();
    if ($condition) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
add_filter('lazyload_is_enabled', 'is_lazyload_activated');
```

Now things are working again. Shame that can't have the optimization plugins working at the same time. At least the code above allows lazy loading on all pages except for the product pages though.

Comment: Nice job tracking that down. Both JetPack and WooCommerce are from Automattic, so if they're not compatible it might be worth reporting that to them too.

Comment: Good point! Will pass it on..

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is flex slider in This page.

Put This script in footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   
    jQuery('.flex-viewport').css('height', 525);

    jQuery('.flex-control-nav li').on('click',function(){
       
        jQuery('.flex-viewport').css('height', 525);
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: I think a better fix would be to work out why the flex-viewport is being created with the wrong height. 525 might only be specific to that one item.

Comment: flex slider js work on their content height and set their view port

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a try with that. Can I ask how you diagnosed what was going on?

Comment: If you use your browser's debug tools to inspect the page and explore the DOM tree a bit you'll find an element `<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position relative; height: 730px;">` It's most obvious if you trigger a resize with the elements tab open and you'll see it change.

Comment: Thanks @Rup - I guess I am on the same page as you now. Wondering why it's being created with the wrong height in the first place. I have set the Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images thumbnails to 'uncropped' and all the images are the same size so unsure why the height would be fluctuating around so much :/